# PPTP VPN connection, authentication failed

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, pptp

I trying establish VPN connection using PPTP on Centos 6.
But receive error.

Log file:

```
May 11 22:50:55 server pppd[1069]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
May 11 22:50:55 server pppd[1069]: Using interface ppp0
May 11 22:50:55 server pppd[1069]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
May 11 22:50:55 server pptp[1070]: anon log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
May 11 22:50:55 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
May 11 22:50:55 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
May 11 22:50:55 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 526).
May 11 22:50:56 server pppd[1069]: MS-CHAP authentication failed: bad username or password
May 11 22:50:56 server pppd[1069]: CHAP authentication failed
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
May 11 22:50:56 server pptp[1078]: anon log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
May 11 22:50:56 server pppd[1069]: Modem hangup
May 11 22:50:56 server pppd[1069]: Connection terminated.
May 11 22:50:57 server pppd[1069]: Exit.
```

Config file

```
pty "pptp IP --nolaunchpppd"
lock
noauth
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
name username
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
require-mschap-v2
nodefaultroute
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
```

options.pptp

```
lock
noauth
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate
```

chap-secrets

```
username PPTP pass *
```

Comment: PPTP is insecure. Do not use it. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security

Comment: PPTP is *not* a VPN since there's no encryption. PPTP is a tunneling protocol only and should not be used outside a private network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often you need to specify a domain with username.

i.e. DOMAIN\password

What type of VPN service are you connecting to?

Failing that, comment out\remove require-mppe-128 and try again.

If neither of those help individually or together, enable debug logging and post the output i.e. run with logfd 2 (see below)

http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#debug